# Log4net logs unknown event: "DEBUG static Execute"

Tags: c#, log4net

I create and configure log4net only in c# code (not in the config).
When I run application, not only my logs get into log files but also something
like that:

```
2018-03-21 11:33:00,312 DEBUG static Execute
2018-03-21 11:33:00,313 DEBUG Execute
2018-03-21 11:33:00,316 DEBUG static Execute
2018-03-21 11:33:00,318 DEBUG Execute
2018-03-21 11:33:00,323 DEBUG static Execute
2018-03-21 11:33:00,324 DEBUG Execute
```

I don't know how I could get rid of that and where it comes from...

I tried to:

```
Logger l = (Logger)result._logger.Logger;
l.Level = Level.Info; (From All to Info)
```

Or even set this:

```
log4net.Util.LogLog.InternalDebugging = false;
```

But None from the above seems to work ...

Comment: Maybe this is something that is logged from an Nuget Package you are using? And because you are using Log4Net it registers itself on that

Comment: I am using Quartz from nuget but ... how could I disable this?

Comment: specify what assemblies will be logged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting this in the config

```
<!-- Print only messages of level WARN or above in the package Com.Foo -->
<logger name="Com.Foo">
    <level value="WARN" />
</logger>
```

Where `Com.Foo` will be `Quartz namespace` and set that to WARN or ERROR
This way you can make sure that that is the problem. I don't know how you can specify a logger specific per Assembly in code but this should help you look for it.

[Documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html)

Comment: Your answer helped me to trackdown the issue. I logged the type that logged an event which led me to another assembly. I fixed the problem. Thanks a lot!